# JAXBContextImpl causing huge retained heap

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, cxf

Our code is creating multiple instances of `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl` which is causing huge retained heap. This in turn chokes the server. We are using `JAXB 2.2.1` with `CXF` and `Spring` and deal with very complex `hrxml` schemas.
Has anyone else faced this ? It is not a memory leak just that `32` instances occupy `603` MB.

Comment: Just a side-note: JAXBContext is thread safe and you can (and probably are) just creating it once (for a schema) and reusing it forever. Also, you might try loading all of your packages into one context via `JAXBContext.newInstance("package1:package2")` and see if things are any better overall.

Comment: I am not calling newInstance() explicitly . I am generating jaxb classes from a xsd , the shallow size (for 4 objects) is 352 but retained size is 104,009,896.

Comment: I suppose generating jaxb from XSD is not part of JVM heap. why not generate it in build process.

Comment: To clarify, the "normal" way to use JAXB is to use xjc at build-time to create Java classes from your xsd files. Then, at runtime you create a JAXBContext from the packages of generated code. For each document you create a new (un)marshaller from the context and convert the document. Are you doing something different from this? If so, you probably should edit the details into your question along with the relevant code.

Comment: Did you able to sort out your issue ?